# Find Matrix A given 2 Eigenvalues and 2 Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find Matrix $A \in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ given Eigenvectors $v_{1}=(0,1,1)^{\top}$ with $\lambda_{1}=1$
and $v_{2}=(0,1,0)^{\top}$ with $\lambda_{2}=0$
My idea is to complete the Matrix $S$ with $v_{3}=(1,0,0)^{\top}$ (I already don't know if I'm on the right track with this) to make it invertible. So here is my attempt to solve it. $S=\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right), S^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right), D=\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$
$A=\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$

I'd like to know if it's correct. I was not sure if I could choose $D$ to have another $0$  along the diagonal in the sense to map $v_{3}=(1,0,0)^{\top}$ to $(0,0,0)^{\top}$ and also not sure about $S$ with $v_{3}$ completed. Since $Av_{1}=v_{1}$ and $Av_{2}=0$ I thought it might be correct, but I hope for further insight thanks.

Comment: Your answer is correct. 
Little note: if it is not said in your exercise that the given eigenvectors should be the only eigenvectors of the eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, then your answer is correct. If the exercise would want that you could just choose $v_3=(1,0,0)^T$ to be an eigenvector of another eigenvalue, e.g. of $2$. Then you would have only the given eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $1$ and $0$.

Comment: Thanks, So there could be 2 possible ways to solve it depending on the question, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.